# Exceptions in NHibernate when using named sql query for full text index search

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sql, named

I am implementing a full text search using a view vw_SearchSite which has all the searchable fields and returning sites which have site IDs in common with the search results.

**the query:**

.....

```
<return alias="site" class="Site"/>

SELECT DISTINCT {site.*}
FROM v_Site {site}
WHERE {site}.Id IN (
  SELECT Id
  FROM vw_SearchSite
  WHERE CONTAINS(vw_SearchSite.*,:pattern)
)
```

**the implementation:**

```
 public Site[] GetSitesforSearch(string search)
    {
        using (var session = GetSession())
        {

            var q1 = session.GetNamedQuery("SearchSite").SetString("pattern", search);
            var q2 = q1.List<Site>().ToArray();
            return q2;
        }
    }
```

**the exception when I unit test it:**

```
in expected: {site} [SELECT DISTINCT {site.*}
FROM v_Site {site}
WHERE {site}.Id IN (
  SELECT Id
  FROM vw_SearchSite
  WHERE CONTAINS(vw_SearchSite.*,:pattern)
)]
```

I have full permissions to the localhost database. I tried all permutations and combinations I could with the above code and failed to figure a way out. the query is working absolutely fine when I executed it in SQL SERVER management studio.

**This is My Unit Test:**

public void Getsitesforsearch_returns_all_matching_sites_test()
        {
            //Arrange
            const string search = "abc";
            var country = _entityBuilder.CreateCountry();
            country.Name = "wall country";
            var country1 = _entityBuilder.CreateCountry();
            country.Name = "crappy country";
            var state1 = _entityBuilder.CreateState();
            state1.Country = country;
            var state2 = _entityBuilder.CreateState();
            state2.Country = country1;
            state1.Name = "wall state";
            state1.Abbreviation = "WS";
            state2.Name = "crap";
            state2.Abbreviation = "CR";

```
        var site1 = _entityBuilder.CreateSite();
        var site2 = _entityBuilder.CreateSite();
        var site3 = _entityBuilder.CreateSite();
        var site4 = _entityBuilder.CreateSite();

        site1.Name = "abc";
        site1.City = "wallsite";
        site1.PostalCode = "33333";
        site1.State = state2;

        site2.State = state2;
        site2.City = "wallsite";
        site2.PostalCode = "44444";
        site2.Name = "site wall";

        site3.State = state1;
        site3.City = "wallsite";
        site3.PostalCode = "55555";
        site3.Name = "site";

        site4.City = "walstreet";
        site4.PostalCode = "66666";
        site4.Name = "site wall";
        site4.State = state2;

        PersistEntities(state1, state2, country1,country);
        PersistEntities(site1,site2,site3,site4);
        var sites = new[] {site2,site3,site4};

        //Act
        var repository = CreateRepository();
        var result = repository.GetSitesforSearch(search);

        //Assert
        result.ShouldNotContain(site1);
        result.ShouldEqual(sites) ;
        result.ShouldContain(site2);
        result.ShouldContain(site3);
        result.ShouldContain(site4);

    }
```

**This is the error:**

**SiteRepositoryTester.Getsitesforsearch_returns_all_matching_sites_test : Failed**

NHibernate: select deviceinst0_.Id as Id5_, deviceinst0_.Name as Name5_, deviceinst0_.Latitude as Latitude5_, deviceinst0_.Longitude as Longitude5_, deviceinst0_.InstallationDate as Installa5_5_, deviceinst0_.RemovalDate as RemovalD6_5_, deviceinst0_.DeviceId as DeviceId5_, deviceinst0_.PrimaryGroupId as PrimaryG8_5_, deviceinst0_.SecondaryGroupId as Secondar9_5_ from tg.v_DeviceInstall deviceinst0_
NHibernate: select basestatio0_.BaseStationId as BaseStat1_4_, basestatio0_.BaseId as BaseId4_, basestatio0_.InstalledOn as Installe3_4_, basestatio0_.SiteId as SiteId4_ from tg.vw_BaseStation basestatio0_
NHibernate: select threshold0_.Id as Id8_, threshold0_.ReadingTypeId as ReadingT2_8_, threshold0_.UpperBound as UpperBound8_, threshold0_.LowerBound as LowerBound8_, threshold0_.DeviceInstallId as DeviceIn5_8_ from tg.v_Threshold threshold0_
NHibernate: select state0_.Id as Id9_, state0_.Name as Name9_, state0_.Abbreviation as Abbrevia3_9_, state0_.CountryId as CountryId9_ from tg.vw_State state0_
NHibernate: select devicegrou0_.Id as Id0_, devicegrou0_.Name as Name0_, devicegrou0_.OldId as OldId0_, devicegrou0_.DeviceGroupTypeId as DeviceGr4_0_, devicegrou0_.SiteId as SiteId0_ from tg.vw_DeviceGroup devicegrou0_
NHibernate: select user0_.Id as Id2_, user0_.Username as Username2_, user0_.Password as Password2_, user0_.FirstName as FirstName2_, user0_.LastName as LastName2_ from tg.v_User user0_
NHibernate: select site0_.Id as Id10_, site0_.Name as Name10_, site0_.Address as Address10_, site0_.City as City10_, site0_.PostalCode as PostalCode10_, site0_.Latitude as Latitude10_, site0_.Longitude as Longitude10_, site0_.PrimaryGroupName as PrimaryG8_10_, site0_.SecondaryGroupName as Secondar9_10_, site0_.StateId as StateId10_ from tg.v_Site site0_
NHibernate: select device0_.Id as Id7_, device0_.DeviceTypeId as DeviceTy2_7_, device0_.Name as Name7_, device0_.NodeId as NodeId7_, device0_.SiteId as SiteId7_ from tg.v_Device device0_
NHibernate: select connection0_.ConnectionId as Connecti1_6_, connection0_.RemoteIP as RemoteIP6_, connection0_.ConnectedOn as Connecte3_6_, connection0_.DisconnectedOn as Disconne4_6_, connection0_.BaseStationId as BaseStat5_6_ from tg.vw_BaseConnection connection0_
NHibernate: select country0_.Id as Id1_, country0_.Name as Name1_ from tg.vw_Country country0_
NHibernate: INSERT INTO tg.vw_Country (Name) VALUES (@p0); select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); @p0 = 'United States'
NHibernate: INSERT INTO tg.vw_State (Name, Abbreviation, CountryId) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2); select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); @p0 = 'Minnesota', @p1 = 'MN', @p2 = '347'
NHibernate: 
NHibernate: INSERT INTO tg.vw_Country (Name) VALUES (@p0); select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); @p0 = 'United States'
NHibernate: INSERT INTO tg.vw_State (Name, Abbreviation, CountryId) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2); select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); @p0 = 'Minnesota', @p1 = 'MN', @p2 = '348'
NHibernate: 
NHibernate: INSERT INTO tg.vw_Country (Name) VALUES (@p0); select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); @p0 = 'United States'
NHibernate: INSERT INTO tg.vw_Country (Name) VALUES (@p0); select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); @p0 = 'crappy country'
NHibernate: 
NHibernate: INSERT INTO tg.v_Site (Name, Address, City, PostalCode, Latitude, Longitude, PrimaryGroupName, SecondaryGroupName, StateId) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8); select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); @p0 = 'abc', @p1 = '12343 Testing Blvd', @p2 = 'wallsite', @p3 = '33333', @p4 = '55', @p5 = '-92.2', @p6 = 'Pri', @p7 = 'Sec', @p8 = '181'
NHibernate: INSERT INTO tg.v_Site (Name, Address, City, PostalCode, Latitude, Longitude, PrimaryGroupName, SecondaryGroupName, StateId) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8); select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); @p0 = 'site wall', @p1 = '12343 Testing Blvd', @p2 = 'wallsite', @p3 = '44444', @p4 = '55', @p5 = '-92.2', @p6 = 'Pri', @p7 = 'Sec', @p8 = '181'
NHibernate: INSERT INTO tg.v_Site (Name, Address, City, PostalCode, Latitude, Longitude, PrimaryGroupName, SecondaryGroupName, StateId) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8); select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); @p0 = 'site', @p1 = '12343 Testing Blvd', @p2 = 'wallsite', @p3 = '55555', @p4 = '55', @p5 = '-92.2', @p6 = 'Pri', @p7 = 'Sec', @p8 = '180'
NHibernate: INSERT INTO tg.v_Site (Name, Address, City, PostalCode, Latitude, Longitude, PrimaryGroupName, SecondaryGroupName, StateId) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8); select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); @p0 = 'site wall', @p1 = '12343 Testing Blvd', @p2 = 'walstreet', @p3 = '66666', @p4 = '55', @p5 = '-92.2', @p6 = 'Pri', @p7 = 'Sec', @p8 = '181'

NHibernate: SELECT DISTINCT site.Id as Id10_0_, site.Name as Name10_0_, site.Address as Address10_0_, site.City as City10_0_, site.PostalCode as PostalCode10_0_, site.Latitude as Latitude10_0_, site.Longitude as Longitude10_0_, site.PrimaryGroupName as PrimaryG8_10_0_, site.SecondaryGroupName as Secondar9_10_0_, site.StateId as StateId10_0_
    FROM v_Site site
    WHERE site.Id IN (
      SELECT Id
      FROM vw_SearchSite
      WHERE CONTAINS(vw_SearchSite.*,@p0)
    ); @p0 = 'abc'

NHibernate: select deviceinst0_.Id as Id5_, deviceinst0_.Name as Name5_, deviceinst0_.Latitude as Latitude5_, deviceinst0_.Longitude as Longitude5_, deviceinst0_.InstallationDate as Installa5_5_, deviceinst0_.RemovalDate as RemovalD6_5_, deviceinst0_.DeviceId as DeviceId5_, deviceinst0_.PrimaryGroupId as PrimaryG8_5_, deviceinst0_.SecondaryGroupId as Secondar9_5_ from tg.v_DeviceInstall deviceinst0_
NHibernate: select basestatio0_.BaseStationId as BaseStat1_4_, basestatio0_.BaseId as BaseId4_, basestatio0_.InstalledOn as Installe3_4_, basestatio0_.SiteId as SiteId4_ from tg.vw_BaseStation basestatio0_
NHibernate: select threshold0_.Id as Id8_, threshold0_.ReadingTypeId as ReadingT2_8_, threshold0_.UpperBound as UpperBound8_, threshold0_.LowerBound as LowerBound8_, threshold0_.DeviceInstallId as DeviceIn5_8_ from tg.v_Threshold threshold0_
NHibernate: select state0_.Id as Id9_, state0_.Name as Name9_, state0_.Abbreviation as Abbrevia3_9_, state0_.CountryId as CountryId9_ from tg.vw_State state0_
NHibernate: select devicegrou0_.Id as Id0_, devicegrou0_.Name as Name0_, devicegrou0_.OldId as OldId0_, devicegrou0_.DeviceGroupTypeId as DeviceGr4_0_, devicegrou0_.SiteId as SiteId0_ from tg.vw_DeviceGroup devicegrou0_
NHibernate: select user0_.Id as Id2_, user0_.Username as Username2_, user0_.Password as Password2_, user0_.FirstName as FirstName2_, user0_.LastName as LastName2_ from tg.v_User user0_
NHibernate: select site0_.Id as Id10_, site0_.Name as Name10_, site0_.Address as Address10_, site0_.City as City10_, site0_.PostalCode as PostalCode10_, site0_.Latitude as Latitude10_, site0_.Longitude as Longitude10_, site0_.PrimaryGroupName as PrimaryG8_10_, site0_.SecondaryGroupName as Secondar9_10_, site0_.StateId as StateId10_ from tg.v_Site site0_
NHibernate: SELECT primarygro0_.SiteId as SiteId1_, primarygro0_.Id as Id1_, primarygro0_.Id as Id0_0_, primarygro0_.Name as Name0_0_, primarygro0_.OldId as OldId0_0_, primarygro0_.DeviceGroupTypeId as DeviceGr4_0_0_, primarygro0_.SiteId as SiteId0_0_ FROM tg.vw_DeviceGroup primarygro0_ WHERE  ((primarygro0_.DeviceGroupTypeId = 1)) and primarygro0_.SiteId=@p0; @p0 = '381'
NHibernate: SELECT secondaryg0_.SiteId as SiteId1_, secondaryg0_.Id as Id1_, secondaryg0_.Id as Id0_0_, secondaryg0_.Name as Name0_0_, secondaryg0_.OldId as OldId0_0_, secondaryg0_.DeviceGroupTypeId as DeviceGr4_0_0_, secondaryg0_.SiteId as SiteId0_0_ FROM tg.vw_DeviceGroup secondaryg0_ WHERE  ((secondaryg0_.DeviceGroupTypeId = 2)) and secondaryg0_.SiteId=@p0; @p0 = '381'
NHibernate: SELECT primarygro0_.SiteId as SiteId1_, primarygro0_.Id as Id1_, primarygro0_.Id as Id0_0_, primarygro0_.Name as Name0_0_, primarygro0_.OldId as OldId0_0_, primarygro0_.DeviceGroupTypeId as DeviceGr4_0_0_, primarygro0_.SiteId as SiteId0_0_ FROM tg.vw_DeviceGroup primarygro0_ WHERE  ((primarygro0_.DeviceGroupTypeId = 1)) and primarygro0_.SiteId=@p0; @p0 = '382'
NHibernate: SELECT secondaryg0_.SiteId as SiteId1_, secondaryg0_.Id as Id1_, secondaryg0_.Id as Id0_0_, secondaryg0_.Name as Name0_0_, secondaryg0_.OldId as OldId0_0_, secondaryg0_.DeviceGroupTypeId as DeviceGr4_0_0_, secondaryg0_.SiteId as SiteId0_0_ FROM tg.vw_DeviceGroup secondaryg0_ WHERE  ((secondaryg0_.DeviceGroupTypeId = 2)) and secondaryg0_.SiteId=@p0; @p0 = '382'
NHibernate: SELECT primarygro0_.SiteId as SiteId1_, primarygro0_.Id as Id1_, primarygro0_.Id as Id0_0_, primarygro0_.Name as Name0_0_, primarygro0_.OldId as OldId0_0_, primarygro0_.DeviceGroupTypeId as DeviceGr4_0_0_, primarygro0_.SiteId as SiteId0_0_ FROM tg.vw_DeviceGroup primarygro0_ WHERE  ((primarygro0_.DeviceGroupTypeId = 1)) and primarygro0_.SiteId=@p0; @p0 = '383'
NHibernate: SELECT secondaryg0_.SiteId as SiteId1_, secondaryg0_.Id as Id1_, secondaryg0_.Id as Id0_0_, secondaryg0_.Name as Name0_0_, secondaryg0_.OldId as OldId0_0_, secondaryg0_.DeviceGroupTypeId as DeviceGr4_0_0_, secondaryg0_.SiteId as SiteId0_0_ FROM tg.vw_DeviceGroup secondaryg0_ WHERE  ((secondaryg0_.DeviceGroupTypeId = 2)) and secondaryg0_.SiteId=@p0; @p0 = '383'
NHibernate: SELECT primarygro0_.SiteId as SiteId1_, primarygro0_.Id as Id1_, primarygro0_.Id as Id0_0_, primarygro0_.Name as Name0_0_, primarygro0_.OldId as OldId0_0_, primarygro0_.DeviceGroupTypeId as DeviceGr4_0_0_, primarygro0_.SiteId as SiteId0_0_ FROM tg.vw_DeviceGroup primarygro0_ WHERE  ((primarygro0_.DeviceGroupTypeId = 1)) and primarygro0_.SiteId=@p0; @p0 = '384'
NHibernate: SELECT secondaryg0_.SiteId as SiteId1_, secondaryg0_.Id as Id1_, secondaryg0_.Id as Id0_0_, secondaryg0_.Name as Name0_0_, secondaryg0_.OldId as OldId0_0_, secondaryg0_.DeviceGroupTypeId as DeviceGr4_0_0_, secondaryg0_.SiteId as SiteId0_0_ FROM tg.vw_DeviceGroup secondaryg0_ WHERE  ((secondaryg0_.DeviceGroupTypeId = 2)) and secondaryg0_.SiteId=@p0; @p0 = '384'
NHibernate: select device0_.Id as Id7_, device0_.DeviceTypeId as DeviceTy2_7_, device0_.Name as Name7_, device0_.NodeId as NodeId7_, device0_.SiteId as SiteId7_ from tg.v_Device device0_
NHibernate: select connection0_.ConnectionId as Connecti1_6_, connection0_.RemoteIP as RemoteIP6_, connection0_.ConnectedOn as Connecte3_6_, connection0_.DisconnectedOn as Disconne4_6_, connection0_.BaseStationId as BaseStat5_6_ from tg.vw_BaseConnection connection0_
NHibernate: select country0_.Id as Id1_, country0_.Name as Name1_ from tg.vw_Country country0_
NHibernate: SELECT states0_.CountryId as CountryId1_, states0_.Id as Id1_, states0_.Id as Id9_0_, states0_.Name as Name9_0_, states0_.Abbreviation as Abbrevia3_9_0_, states0_.CountryId as CountryId9_0_ FROM tg.vw_State states0_ WHERE states0_.CountryId=@p0; @p0 = '347'
NHibernate: SELECT states0_.CountryId as CountryId1_, states0_.Id as Id1_, states0_.Id as Id9_0_, states0_.Name as Name9_0_, states0_.Abbreviation as Abbrevia3_9_0_, states0_.CountryId as CountryId9_0_ FROM tg.vw_State states0_ WHERE states0_.CountryId=@p0; @p0 = '348'
NHibernate: SELECT states0_.CountryId as CountryId1_, states0_.Id as Id1_, states0_.Id as Id9_0_, states0_.Name as Name9_0_, states0_.Abbreviation as Abbrevia3_9_0_, states0_.CountryId as CountryId9_0_ FROM tg.vw_State states0_ WHERE states0_.CountryId=@p0; @p0 = '349'
NHibernate: SELECT states0_.CountryId as CountryId1_, states0_.Id as Id1_, states0_.Id as Id9_0_, states0_.Name as Name9_0_, states0_.Abbreviation as Abbrevia3_9_0_, states0_.CountryId as CountryId9_0_ FROM tg.vw_State states0_ WHERE states0_.CountryId=@p0; @p0 = '350'
NHibernate: 
NHibernate: 
NHibernate: 
NHibernate:

**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'v_Site'.**

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)

**NHibernate.ADOException: could not execute query**
[ SELECT DISTINCT site.Id as Id10_0_, site.Name as Name10_0_, site.Address as Address10_0_, site.City as City10_0_, site.PostalCode as PostalCode10_0_, site.Latitude as Latitude10_0_, site.Longitude as Longitude10_0_, site.PrimaryGroupName as PrimaryG8_10_0_, site.SecondaryGroupName as Secondar9_10_0_, site.StateId as StateId10_0_
    FROM v_Site site
    WHERE site.Id IN (
      SELECT Id
      FROM vw_SearchSite
      WHERE CONTAINS(vw_SearchSite.*,?)
    ) ]
  Name:pattern - Value:abc
[SQL: SELECT DISTINCT site.Id as Id10_0_, site.Name as Name10_0_, site.Address as Address10_0_, site.City as City10_0_, site.PostalCode as PostalCode10_0_, site.Latitude as Latitude10_0_, site.Longitude as Longitude10_0_, site.PrimaryGroupName as PrimaryG8_10_0_, site.SecondaryGroupName as Secondar9_10_0_, site.StateId as StateId10_0_
    FROM v_Site site
    WHERE site.Id IN (
      SELECT Id
      FROM vw_SearchSite
      WHERE CONTAINS(vw_SearchSite.*,?)
    )]

at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes)
at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ListCustomQuery(ICustomQuery customQuery, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl.List()
at Toro.TurfGuard.Common.Infrastructure.DataAccess.Impl.SiteRepository.GetSitesforSearch(String search) in SiteRepository.cs: line 33
at Toro.TurfGuard.Common.IntegrationTests.Infrastructure.DataAccess.Impl.SiteRepositoryTester.Getsitesforsearch_returns_all_matching_sites_test() in SiteRepositoryTester.cs: line 109

**So, could anyone help me with handling these exceptions. immediate help appreciated.**

Comment: It doesn't look like you included the whole error. Could you include the full message, along with a stack trace?

Comment: I included the full message... couldn't find the stack trace in it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the table name, `v_Site`, correct?

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'v_Site'
```